# How can I get NSE stocks only opening and closing price in Google sheet from Google finance?

Tags: google-sheets, stock, google-finance

I tried using this formula for cells to enter the opening and closing price for mentioned stocks in google sheets.

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "open", A2), 2, 2)
```

Column B has stock symbols mentioned.

but it is always showing

> Error When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol:
> 'RELIANCE.NS' returned no data.

or shows

> #N/A

Tried these other different formulas but didn't worked.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/equities/reliance-industries-historical-data", "//table[@id='curr_table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

- 

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/relianceindustriesindianagrasp/opening-priceRI", "//div[@class='value_txtfl fl gL_10 uc']/span[1]"),1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the ticker name [`NSE:RELIANCE`](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/RELIANCE:NSE?hl=en)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error is related to the query: RELIANCE.NS

Comparing the sample usage from Google documentation, I've tested using NSE:RELIANCE and it worked.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:RELIANCE", "all", TODAY()-(3), TODAY(), "DAILY")
```

**Reference:**

- [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)